# Create bar plot grouped by string label with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a bar plot where the x axis is `type` and the y axis is `price`.  I want to group the bars by each specifict `type` so I can show bars with a total value

```
type        price
cookie        1
cookie        3
brownie       2
candy         4
brownie       4
```

This is what I came up with so far, but it seems to be plotting many different charts

```
ax2 = df_new.groupby([df_new.type]).plot(kind='bar', figsize=(18,7),
                                        color="green", fontsize=13,);
ax2.set_title("Totals", fontsize=18)
ax2.set_ylabel("price", fontsize=18);
ax2.set_xticklabels(df_new['type'])

totals = []

for i in ax2.patches:
    totals.append(i.get_height())
total = sum(totals)

# set individual bar lables using above list
for i in ax2.patches:
    # get_x pulls left or right; get_height pushes up or down
    ax2.text(i.get_x()-.03, i.get_height()+.5, \
            str(round((i.get_height()/total)*100, 2))+'%', fontsize=15,
                color='black')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you may just be missing a sum on your group by and the rest is supported out of the box...

```
data = '''type price
cookie 1
cookie 3
brownie 2
candy 4
brownie 4'''

cols, *data = [i.split(' ') for i in data.splitlines()]

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cols)
df.price = df.price.astype(int)

ax2 = df.groupby('type').sum().plot.bar()
ax2.set_title("Totals", fontsize=18)
ax2.set_ylabel("price", fontsize=18);
```

[image: which yields]